# Logic: Formalization of statements and correct writing of answer

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic, quantifiers, logic-translation

I have following statements:

> 1. Everybody having a musical ear is able to sing properly
> 2. Nobody is a real musician if they can't electrify their audience
> 3. Nobody who does not have a musical ear can electrify their audience
> 4. Nobody, except a real musician, can compose a symphony

And need to answer this question:

> Which properties does a person have who has composed a symphony?

I formalized these statements as follow

1. $M\implies S$
2. $R\implies E$
3. $E\implies M$
4. $C\implies R$

And then concluded that if a person composed a symphony, they have all properties ($R, E, M, S$).

My questions are: is my formalization correct? How can I mathematically correctly write my conclusion? (Since C implies R, and R implies E (...), a person who has composed a symphony satisfies all implied properties)

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Shaun that you need to use quantifiers for these. Also, I would translate more directly, i.e include the negations that clearly appear in 2,3, and 4. So:

1. $\forall x (M(x) \rightarrow S(x))$
2. $\forall x (\neg E(x) \rightarrow \neg R(x))$
3. $\forall x (\neg M(x) \rightarrow \neg E(x))$
4. $\forall x (\neg R(x) \rightarrow \neg C(x))$

By contraposition, 2,3, and 4 are equivalent to:

2'. $\forall x (R(x) \rightarrow E(x))$

3'. $\forall x (E(x) \rightarrow M(x))$

4'. $\forall x (C(x) \rightarrow R(x))$

And now you see that you had all directions of the conditionals correct!

Comment: Thank you, as I was writing, I know I could've used quantifiers, but it was an exercise in propositional logic (there are no quantifiers there right? At least we didn't use them there) as for writing out the solution, is writing the relations enough?

Comment: @user452306 Yes, in that case you can drop the quantifiers and variables (and use $E,R,M,C$ as you did), but I would still recommend writing them with the negations first, and then perform contraposition

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your formalisations are correct, if a little rough.

To be more precise, I would use predicates. For example, $$\forall x(Mx\to Sx)$$ for 1.

Comment: Thank you! Yes I know, but it was specifically an exercise in propositional logic, we don't use quantifiers there, right? That being said, any hint on how I should write the answer ? (Proving that a person who has composed has all these traits)